« Chier contre qqn » : sens (Molloy, Samuel Beckett)
Tiré de Molloy, Samuel Beckett

Mais à vrai dire (à vrai dire !) je n’ai jamais été particulièrement
résolu, je veux dire sujet à prendre des résolutions, mais plutôt
disposé à foncer tête baissée dans la merde, sans savoir qui chiait
contre qui ni de quel côté j’avais intérêt à me planquer.

Le TLFi n'explique pas ce sens. Un texte très ancien comporte ce verbe avec la même préposition ; PROVERBES EN RIMES, OU RIMES EN PROVERBES.: SECONDE PARTIE Philippe le Duc · 1664 le sens dans ce texte ancien n'est pas clair, sauf que l'on peut encore penser à un sens figuré.

Il y a bien plus récent, et c'est évidemment maintenant de l'argot des plus grossier, mais le sens serait « être laid(e) », et celui de l'ancien français serait très probablement le même ; néanmoins, cela n'éclaire pas l'usage qui en est fait par Beckett.

(Les vacances de Bérurier - San-Antonio · 2014) ... Ça tombe bien car elle a déjà une tronche à chier contre, cette personne. L'a de la santé, le Vieux, pour s'enamourer devant une chouette pareille ! Nez crochu, peau fripée, œil torve, bouche sans lèvres, cheveux rouges !

Que signifie " chier contre qqn » ? « Dire du mal de quelqu'un » ? « Créer des ennuis à qqn » ? « nuire à qqn » ? Autre chose ?

Argot des plus grossiers, faut pas exagérer. Pour moi c'est  familier et vulgaire. Mais là n'est pas la question. J'interprète chier contre quelqu'un ici  et d'après ce qui précède et ce qui suit comme se fâcher contre, se battre contre. Pour info la traduction en anglais, par Beckett in person, est: But to tell the truth (to tell the truth!) I have never been particularly resolute, I mean given to resolutions, but rather inclined to plunge headlong, into the shit, without knowing who was shitting against whom or on which side I had the better chance of skulking with success.

@None La grossièreté d'esprit réside justement dans l'extrême exagération, dans l'idée d'associer la laideur physique humaine à des excréments ; elle est loin de susciter une telle répugnance.  (mais il est vrai que l'exagération est une figure de rhétorique, alors pourquoi pas dans ce cas ; il s'agit peut-être d'autre chose que de grossièreté.) // Un anglicisme alors ?

Je ne sais pas si  c'est un anglicisme, ça se dit en français de façon très très très familière, et regarde sur les forums aussi (forums de jeux en particulier.)

Chier contre quelqu'un? Tout simplement "chier accroupi contre lui plutôt que contre le premier mur venu." Un visage "à chier contre" est si laid qu'il dispense de chercher un mur plus propre (si j'ose dire) à cette occupation. Inutile de chercher midi à 14h: le choix de cette préposition est tout naturel, voire le seul possible (sens 3 dans fr.Wkt, https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/contre). VTC.

@FrançoisJurain User None parle de qqc au sens figuré aussi (« fâcher »), et seulement le sens figuré   me semble logique ; il ne s'agit pas de « à chier contre qqc »  mais de « chier contre qqn ».

@FrançoisJurain Je ne pense pas que « contre » soit ce qu'il faut dans le sens littéral ( TLFi Exprime le contact étroit ou le choc au terme d'un déplacement. Il met une échelle contre le mur; il serre son ami contre son cœur; les vagues se brisent contre les rochers ). Le Wiktionnaire enregistre un glissement, néglige le sens premier.

Beckett file la métaphore scatologique, à un "foncer dans la merde" plutôt commun il ajoute l'invention imagée selon laquelle les gens se chient les uns contre les autres, dans une sorte de bagarre d'excréments. C'est une façon de montrer que Molloy n'a pas de disposition naturelle à jauger les situations difficiles, en particulier les conflits humains. En termes moins crus on pourrait dire :

disposé à foncer tête baissée dans le grabuge, sans savoir qui était contre qui ni de quel côté j’avais intérêt à me planquer.


L'explication littéraire en plus n'est pas de trop… Donc, simplement une image (à la Beckett, dans ce qu'il a de plus cru), pas un terme établit (certains ont suggérer « se fâcher »).

En effet, c'est une combinaison de deux mots qui fait tout de suite sens mais pas un idiotisme.

@LPH on peut l'interpréter comme "se fâcher" dans une situation immédiatement conflictuelle, mais pas que : ça pourrait être des querelles de village de plus long terme dans lesquelles le héros met les pieds, des luttes de pouvoir, etc.

Prière de lire « établi » et « suggéré » dans le commentaire précédent ; heureusement votre commentaire me donne une possibilité de relecture.
